# Error in android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Tags: java, javascript, android

Ive got an error when i call this android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
My logcat says it is unable to start activity. as my understanding using kill process is to kill task that is running but when i use this it shows that it is starting to call another activity. 
here is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(S_2nd_LoginActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to cancel?")
                          .setCancelable(false)
                          .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());


                            }
                        })
                          .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                          });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

here is my logcat:

```
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  start activity ComponentInfo{ph.com.example.Project/ph.com.example.Project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at ph.com.example.Project.MainActivity.get_Territory(MainActivity.java:169)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at ph.com.example.Project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
```

here is my method of get Territory:

```
public void get_Territory() {
    String territory = String.valueOf(LoginActivity.g_territory);

    lbl_user.setText(LoginActivity.txt_username.getText().toString());

    String s = l_databaseHandler.get_territoryCode(territory);
    String f = l_databaseHandler.get_doctorFname(s);
    String l = l_databaseHandler.get_doctorLname(s);

    Cursor cursorAllDetails = l_databaseHandler.get_all_sameDoctorname(f, l);

    if (cursorAllDetails.getCount() != 0){
        fillData(cursorAllDetails);
    }else{
        save_territory();
    }

}
```

and i call this method this way on my onCreate:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l_databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    if (l_databaseHandler != null) {
        l_databaseHandler.close();
        l_databaseHandler.createDB();
    }

    Constants.from_add = false;
    Constants.from_edit = false;
    Constants.from_view = false;

    cast_views();

    get_Territory();

    log_out();

          }
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you. I'd use this before and i use it again the same way, i just dont get it why it is acting this way.

Comment: Which error are you getting? can you please provide your logcat output?

Comment: ok, ill post it. wait for my edit. thank you.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 18:28:43.805: E/AndroidRuntime(19417):    at ph.com.example.Project.MainActivity.get_Territory(MainActivity.java:169)

Comment: What is `get_Territory` method ? Please show code of it.

Comment: What is line number 169. Here you are getting null pointer

Comment: yes. it is. ok ill post it. sorry, for incomplete info.

Comment: @Drx Please post the code of your `onCreate()` method along with `get_Territory` method.

Comment: lbl_user.setText(LoginActivity.txt_username.getText().toString()); this is my line 169

Comment: In that method.. what is 169 th line

Comment: Have you initialized `txt_username` TextView in your `LoginActivity` ?

Comment: Yes, it is actually an editText.

Answer (score 2):

TRy like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(S_2nd_LoginActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to cancel?")
                          .setCancelable(false)
                          .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                                finish();


                            }
                        })
                          .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                          });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

And in your `onDestroy()` method call `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Comment: yes, it works but it affect to my log in button it did the same with cancel button.

Comment: try my second solution

Comment: @Drx: It is null pointer Exception. You can solve it very easily. Just post 169 line. You will get direct answer for this

Comment: this is my line 169 lbl_user.setText(LoginActivity.txt_username.getText().toString());

Comment: Good.. In this you are getting null pointer. First check initialization of variables lbl_user, txt_username. then try these lines String name = LoginActivity.txt_username.getText().toString();
if(name != null)
   lbl_user.setText(name);
else
   lbl_user.setText("");

Comment: i still get the same error. Error in line String name = LoginActivity.txt_username.getText().toString();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48947/discussion-between-saa-and-drx)

Comment: Why you are writing like this LoginActivity.txt_username.... Instead just write txt_username.

Comment: :)) i got it.. theres an activity i did not finish on my class.. i didnt know that theres something to do with my class. but i still get your answer this will help me in the future. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText txt_username;
TextView lbl_user;    

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txt_username= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
lbl_user= (TextView )findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);


        l_databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        if (l_databaseHandler != null) {
            l_databaseHandler.close();
            l_databaseHandler.createDB();
        }

        Constants.from_add = false;
        Constants.from_edit = false;
        Constants.from_view = false;

        cast_views();

        get_Territory();

        log_out();

              }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this.

```
String name = LoginActivity.txt_username.getText().toString();
if(name != null)
   lbl_user.setText(name);
else
   lbl_user.setText("");
```